# Download specific piece using libtorrent

Tags: c++, p2p, bittorrent, libtorrent

Well ,I'm working on a bittorent client and I'm trying to generate thumbnails of video files by downloading a specific piece and extracting an image from it , yet I haven't been able to figure out a way to do so.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take you you mean to download specific pieces of a torrent.

First, you probably want to map the beginning of a file to a range of pieces. You can do that with the `torrent_info::map_file()`.

Then you can select which pieces to download by `torrent_handle::prioritize_pieces()`. Setting the priority of a piece to 0, means not to download it.

see [libtorrent documentation](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html)